Definiteness of an integral quadratic form
Given $A:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $x\mapsto A(x)$ with eig$\big(A(x)\big)\subset \mathbb C^-:= \{\lambda \in \mathbb C \vert Re(\lambda) <0\}$ for all $x$.
Given also $\mathbb R^{n\times n}\ni P = P^\top \succ 0$.
Show that $$x^\top \left(\int_0^1 A(\sigma x)^\top  d\sigma  P \int_0^1 A(\sigma x ) d\sigma \right) x$$ is positive definite for all $x$ in the sense of $x^\top (...) x > 0 \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$.
Hint: It is true.
My ideas:

To show that this is true, it would be enough if we could conclude invertibility of $T(x) :=\int_0^1 A(\sigma x ) d\sigma$. Then, it follows by congruence that $T^\top PT \succ 0 \Leftrightarrow P \succ 0 $. So far I have failed to conclude this though.
Certainly $A(\sigma x)$ is invertible for all $\sigma x \in \mathbb R^n, \sigma \in [0,1]$, since $A(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

We could perhaps try to lower bound the quadratic form by a similar one that only has one integrand which is clearly positive definite. I have not found one yet. If the integrand is positive definite, then also the resulting matrix after definite integration will be positive definite.

We may be able to split up the original quadratic form into its symmetric and skew parts, the skew parts will not contribute. If we have the symmetric part of $A$, we know it is negative definite. The integral over this part will again be negative definite, from which we can conclude again like in 1. by congruence the result.


